# File locking with Fcntl: Baffling bug involving 'use' and 'require'

Tags: perl, debugging, namespaces, locking

The following Perl script outputs "SUCCESS" as you'd expect:

```
use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock);
sysopen(LF, "test.txt", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT) or die "SYSOPEN FAIL: $!";
if(flock(LF, LOCK_EX)) { print "SUCCESS.\n"; }
else { print "FAIL: $!\n"; }
```

But now, replace that first line with

```
require "testlib.pl";
```

where testlib.pl contains

```
use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock);

1;
```

Now, strangely enough, the script fails, like so:

```
FAIL: Bad file descriptor
```

The question: Why?

ADDED:

And now that I know why -- thanks! -- I'm wondering what is the best way to deal with this:

1. Just do the `use Fcntl` twice, once in the main script and once in the required library (both the main script and the library need it).
2. Replace O_RDONLY with &O_RDONLY, etc.
3. Replace O_RDONLY with O_RDONLY(), etc.
4. Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock);` is not just loading the Fcntl library for you, but also exporting some symbols into your script's namespace.  If you move that to a different scope, then the constants O_RDONLY, O_CREAT, LF, and LOCK_EX are no longer available to you, and your code won't do the same thing <sub>[however you could still reach them, if you know what namespace they ended up in -- since it was a script that did the export, you could call &main::NAME or simply &NAME, but then you have to be aware of what another file is doing with its code, which is not very clean]</sub>.

This is described in the documentation under [EXPORTED SYMBOLS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Fcntl#EXPORTED_SYMBOLS):

> By default your system's F_* and O_* constants (eg, F_DUPFD and O_CREAT) and the FD_CLOEXEC constant are exported into your namespace.
>
> You can request that the flock() constants (LOCK_SH, LOCK_EX, LOCK_NB and LOCK_UN) be provided by using the tag ":flock".  See Exporter.

If you add the lines

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to the top of your script, you will get more informative error messages such as "Name "main::O_RDONLY" used only once: possible type at line ...", which would give you a clue that these constants definitions are no longer visible.

Edit: in response to your question, the best practice would be #1, to include
the use statement in every file that needs it. See [perldoc -f use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) -- the Fcntl library is only included once, but the import() call is made every time it is needed, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Ether! Mystery solved!  In my actual application, I need to "use Fcntl" in both the main script and testlib.pl, which the main script `require`s.  Is that fine to do "use Fcntl" twice or is there a better way?  Php addresses this with the require_once command.  I'm not sure if there's an equivalent in Perl.  Maybe this should be a separate question...

Comment: Just to clarify - the subs (LOCK_EX, etc.) *are* available in the `main::` namespace, it's just that the un-strict parser does not recognize their naked names as parameterless subs, as in @Sean's answer.

Comment: @dreeves: The best practice would be to include the use statement in every file that needs it. See `perldoc -f use` -- the Fcntl library is only included once, but the `import()` call is made every time it is needed, which is what you want.

Comment: Ah, you just answered the question I appended.  Thanks again, and to @Sean and @pilcrow as well!

Comment: @pilcrow: good point - if the `use` call is moved to a different script the symbols are imported to main:: where they would be usable as `&NAME`. If on the other hand the use statement was moved to another package, the symbols would be in that package's namespace, where `&LOCK_SH` still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

By foregoing `use`, you deprive the Perl parser of the knowledge that `O_RDONLY` et al. are parameterless subroutines.  You have to be a bit more verbose in that situation:

```
sysopen(LF, "test.txt", O_RDONLY() | O_CREAT()) or die "SYSOPEN FAIL: $!";
if(flock(LF, LOCK_EX())) { print "SUCCESS.\n"; }
```

EDIT: To elaborate a bit further, without the parentheses, the `O_RDONLY` and `O_CREAT` were being interpreted as barewords (strings), which don't behave as you'd expect when binary-or'ed together:

```
$ perl -le 'print O_RDONLY | O_CREAT'
O_SVOO\Y
```

(The individual characters are being bitwise or'ed togther.)

In this case, the string "O_SVOO\Y" (or whatever it is on your system) was being interpreted as the number 0 to `sysopen`, which would therefore still work as long as `O_RDONLY` is 0 (as is typical) and the file already existed (so the `O_CREAT` was superfluous).  But `fcntl` is apparently not as forgiving with non-numeric arguments:

```
$ perl -e 'flock STDOUT, "LOCK_EX" or die "Failed: $!"'
Failed: Bad file descriptor at -e line 1.
```

Similarly:

```
$ perl -e 'flock STDOUT, LOCK_EX or die "Failed: $!"'
Failed: Bad file descriptor at -e line 1.
```

However:

```
$ perl -e 'use Fcntl qw(:flock); flock STDOUT, LOCK_EX or die "Failed: $!"'
(no output)
```

Finally, note that `use strict` provides many helpful clues.

Comment: +1  This is right.  @dreeves' example works for me if I explicitly call LOCK_EX as a sub, e.g., `&LOCK_EX`.  (Please don't call the ampersand police.)

Answer (score 0):

use is equivalent to:

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
```

guaranteeing that the import functions are available before the code starts executing.  Whe you replace use with require, it simply reads the code in at the lexical point in the program where it exists.